# 1994 Honda Accord EX (F22B1) - Valves still making a ticking noise

Tags: honda, noise, accord, valve, vtec

I have a 94 Honda accord Ex (F22B1). When I bought it a few days ago the previous owner mentioned a few of the issues that he could remember. Since I've only ever owned Honda's and have worked on them for some time I figured there wasn't a problem I couldn't fix. This one has me a little perplexed. I started it up and noticed that valve ?tapets? (sorry don't know what they are really called) were all loose and making noise. That night after the engine had a good chance to cool down I took the valve cover off and used my old trick of a 1/4 turn loosen on all the valves from full tightness. (Side note: This wasn't a blind un-thought out process. if you want to know more we can chat about it)

Put it all back together and it went from a full on clickity clakity motor to much quieter engine. However one of the valves is still making noise. I figured that because I did it sorta late and in a hurry that I didn't do as good of a job as I should have. So after driving it 120 miles the past few days and a much needed oil change I figured it was a good enough time to let the valves settle to their new clearance and decided to tighten them up again today but this time take more time doing it. Get it back together and one of them is still making noise. I'm fairly certain it is the #1 cyclinder's valves but I am still kinda guessing on that. Anywho I've just never had that happen to me before where it was still making noise after adjusting all of the valves. Any suggestions?

Last question: How do I know it's not the rod bearings? I used to think it was speed between clicking noises, but when I put my head in different areas of the engine bay it sounds like it's coming from the front of the engine and gets louder when I put my head closer to the exhaust manifold instead of next to the valve cover.

Answer (score 4):

Set the valve clearance with feeler gauges. Exhaust .012" Intake .010".  30 yrs of Honda and I still do not trust any other method. If one of my employees does not use gauges we will be having a chat...

Rod knock is usually much more evident on acceleration and not heard at idle until the damage is quite advanced. The noise can vary but is usually a lower pitch than valve tick.

Possible causes of valve train tick. Worn camshaft lobe. Sticking valve. Sticking rocker arm bearing. Loose timing belt sprocket bolt. Worn cam bearings.
If this has the V-tec system then that opens up other possibilities.

Comment: It does have vtec.  Or as I love to say V-TEEEECHHH Because of how frequent I hear it.

Answer (score 1):

98-009

April 13,1999

Applies To:
1995-97 Accord-All Ohio-built LX and DX models

Ticking Noise From the Valve Train
(Supersedes 98-009, dated June 23, 1998)

SYMPTOM
Ticking noise from the valve train.

PROBABLE CAUSE
Intake rocker arm shaft clearance is excessive at the number two cylinder.

CORRECTIVE ACTION
Adjust the valve clearances, or replace the cam holder and the adjoining intake rocker arm shafts at the number two cylinder.

PARTS INFORMATION
Cam Holder kit/N 12010-P0B-305, H/C 5686423

Looks like it just took a while for yours to act up. It says 1995, but thats just Honda trying to cover their butts. This issue has been around since very late 80's

The guy above me is probably right, I was just adding proof to his answer; If it solves your issue please upvote him.

Comment: But that looks like for non vtec models... Although the symptom sounds right. I'll give it a try

Comment: The system they designed the valve train around was VERY similar between the non VTEC and VTEC valve-train. If you adjust the valves, invest in a really good set of feeler gauges. They might cost a bit more, but I've done some personal research and study on how accurate the cheaper sets are; They are usually incorrect. adjusting valves on those engines is a little quirky too. I hope you get it figured out.

Comment: I've got my old set of feeler gauges. The ticking has gone down but hasn't gone away... so looks like I'm back to looking into the cam holder.I'm thinking what I'll do is wait on it and just get all new parts for the head (some upgraded of course).

Answer (score -1):

Change the head gasket head just clean  check head face clearness and check valves sites rocker's valve seals make a new car