# Ticking after much engine work

Tags: honda, noise, accord, valve

This question is a follow up to this question: [1994 Honda Accord EX (F22B1) - Valves still making a ticking noise](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/22692/12739)

Work I've done

- Replaced head

  - New valves, new seals new gaskets
  - verified different <s>push thingy</s> `Lost Motion Assemblies` on intake was in spec and got all the air bubbles out before installing
  - triple checked torque
  - triple checked valve clearance
- New rod bearings
- New Main bearings
- new thrust washers

Cranked it up expecting no noise, but still heard a ticking. While engine was idling I got under car to double check bolts and wires and things and thought that I heard the noise coming from a bearing. Ordered new main, rods, and thrust bearings and just replaced all those. Still have a loud ticking noise. I probably should have went after the rocker arm assembly and at this point that is what I'm thinking is wrong anyway. (Should have listened in the first place) Having looked at those <s>push thingies</s> `Lost Motion Assemblies` I noticed that the 2nd and 3rd cylinder's was worn a bunch more on the top then 1 and 4... Now that I'm saying it out loud I should have taken that as a hint. So my question is where can I get the parts to rebuild that thing (if such a kit exists?) I've searched amazon to no avail (maybe just typing in wrong thing) or should I just get a whole new rocker arm assembly. I'm just kind of upset right now so maybe I shouldn't be posting.

Comment: Check http://www.hondapartsguys.com; I order parts for an '01 Prelude there all the time. Sometimes things get back-ordered and take a few extra days but they haven't let me down yet (ymmv with a '94 vehicle). [For example](http://www.hondapartsguys.com/auto-parts/1994/honda/accord-sedan/ex-trim/5-speed-manual-engine/engine-cat/valve-rocker-arm-2-scat/). The parts are all OE, and new; they can get pricey but not as pricey as the dealer. Otherwise you're scavenging junkyards or eBay.